# How to get soft keyboard height/open/close notification

Tags: android

I am facing a weird scenario in developing an Android app.
I need to notify some components of my app on soft keyboard open/close and also supply them the keyboard height so they can react accordingly.
I tried following;

```
getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
        }
});
```

But It's not working fine on 4.2.2 neither seems logical to me, as one need to specify a discrete difference in layout properties to perceive as keyboard events. I Surfed internet a lot but couldn't find something really helping. Any help me in this regard will be highly appreciated .

Thanks,
Ammar

Comment: @323go onConfigurationChanged() is never invoked for soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this question after long time, though I should add my approach so that it might be helpful for others.

First I added an invisible `Layout` 'invisible_layout' in my UI just to keep track of the size updates. Then added `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on this `Layout` to listen for layout updates. On resizing, the `Layout`'s full height and updated was used to pre-empt keyboard appearance.

```
int prevViewHeight = 0;

public void keyboardObserver() {
    final View containerView = findViewById(R.id.invisible_layout);

    containerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if(prevViewHeight != containerView.getHeight()){
                prevViewHeight = containerView.getHeight();

                int heightDiff = containerView.getRootView().getHeight() - containerView.getHeight();
                // heightDiff is the height of the keyboard

                if (heightDiff > heightComparator() ) { // if more than 100 dp, its probably a keyboard...
                    if ( heightDiff > heightComparator() ) {
                        // do what is required on keyboard show
                    } else {
                        // do what is required on keyboard hide
                    }
                }


        }
    });
}

public int heightComparator() {

    Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int height = 0;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13){
        height = mDisplay.getHeight();
    } else
    {
        Point size = new Point();
        mDisplay.getSize(size);
        height = size.y;
    }

    return height / 3; // I'm assuming that if the resized height is greate than 1/3 of the screen height, then keyboard is displayed
}
```

Suggestions for optimization are welcome.